# High Schooler (Advanced Linear Algebra Help)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

My teacher gave us a homework problem that is considered an "advanced topic" that we have not really delved deeply into yet. I'm struggling to connect the dots in the question to formulate my answer.

I assume that I will be constructing a system of linear equations that gives solutions d, -b, -c, and a. My question is how the basis U = (1, t, t^2, t^3) relates to T(at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d) so that I can move forward and solve this problem.

[image: Homework Question]

Answer (score 4):

To find the matrix of your transformation, see what the transformation does to each basis element.

For instance: to find the third column of the matrix, see what $T$ does to the third element of $U$, $t^2$.  If $M$ denotes the matrix of the transformation, then we find that (in the notation [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector))
$$
M \pmatrix{0\\0\\1\\0} = M [t^2]_U = [T(t^2)]_B = \left[\pmatrix{0&-1\\0&0}\right]_B = \pmatrix{0\\-1\\0\\0}
$$
So, the matrix we're looking for has the form
$$
M = \pmatrix{?&?&0&?\\?&?&-1&?\\?&?&0&?\\?&?&0&?}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have the basis $U=\{ u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4 \}$ and 
$B=\{ b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4 \}$. Then $T$ acts like this:
\begin{align}
T(u_1) &= T(1) =
T(\underbrace{0}_a\cdot t^3 + \underbrace{0}_b\cdot t^2 + \underbrace{0}_c\cdot t + \underbrace{1}_d\cdot 1) =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
= b_1
\\
T(u_2) &= T(t) =
T(\underbrace{0}_a\cdot t^3 + \underbrace{0}_b\cdot t^2 + \underbrace{1}_c\cdot t + \underbrace{0}_d\cdot 1) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
= -b_3
\\
T(u_3) &= T(t^2) =
T(\underbrace{0}_a\cdot t^3 + \underbrace{1}_b\cdot t^2 + \underbrace{0}_c\cdot t + \underbrace{0}_d\cdot 1) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
= -b_2 
\\
T(u_4) &= T(t^3) =
T(\underbrace{1}_a\cdot t^3 + \underbrace{0}_b\cdot t^2 + \underbrace{0}_c\cdot t + \underbrace{0}_d\cdot 1) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
= b_4
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is $$M= \begin {bmatrix} 0&0&0&1\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix} $$

Note that  $$M\begin {pmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix} =\begin {pmatrix} d\\-b\\-c\\a\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The (ordered) basis is $(1, t, t^2, t^3)$, not $(t^3,t^2,t,1)$.